# If $AB=0$, how can I show that $Col(B)$ is a subspace of $Nul(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices such that $AB = 0$. Show that $Col(B)$ is a subspace of $Nul(A)$

Till now i have that $Col(B)$ is the vector $b$, such that $Bx=b$, and from this i get:
$$AB = 0 \Rightarrow ABx = 0x = 0 \Rightarrow ACol(B) = 0$$

I assume that this has something to do with $Nul(A)$ being the set of all x that satisfies the equation $Ax=0$, but i am not quite sure how to link these up to the def. of a subspace.

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

You can prove that $X$ is a subspace of $Y$ by proving

1. That $X$ is a subset of $Y$
2. That $X$ is a vector space.

---

In your case, you need to prove that $col(B)$ is a vector space, which should be fairly obvious.

Additionally, you need to prove that $col(B)$ is a subset of $Nul(A)$, which can be proven like in general like so:

- Take any $b\in Col(B)$.
- Therefore $somethingsomething$
- Therefore, $Ab = 0$
- Therefore, $b\in Nul(A)$
- Therefore, $Col(B)\subseteq Nul(A)$

Now, give it a try and let us know how far you got.

---

**Hint**:

- Let $b_1,b_2\dots$ be the columns of $B$. How are $b_i$ connected to $b$?
- What is $Ab_i$ equal to?
- What is $A(\alpha_1 b_1 + \cdots \alpha_n b_n)$ equal to?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much! This is what I've got so far:

$$Ab_i = ABx_i = 0  $$
Therefore all $$ b_i $$ is in the null space.

$$ A(\alpha_1b_1+...+\alpha_nb_n) = ACol(B)\qquad(?)$$